# A non-numeric value encountered PHP MySQL PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have read through many other posts about this non-numeric value encountered error, but unfortunately, I may be dense. I'm not sure how to fix this annoying error.

Here is my code block:

```
$formula1 = ROUND(($sheetData[$i]['G'] * .6),0);
$formula2 = ROUND(($sheetData[$i]['G'] * .2),0);
$formula3 = ROUND(($sheetData[$i]['G'] * .2),0);
if($sheetData[$i]['G'] == 2 || $sheetData[$i]['G'][-1] == 7){
    $total_quantity = $formula1 + 1;
}else if($sheetData[$i]['G'] == 3 || $sheetData[$i]['G'][-1] == 8){
    $total_quantity = $formula1 - 1;
}else{
    $total_quantity = $formula1;
}
```

The error happens on this line:

```
$formula1 = ROUND(($sheetData[$i]['G'] * .6),0);
$formula2 = ROUND(($sheetData[$i]['G'] * .2),0);
$formula3 = ROUND(($sheetData[$i]['G'] * .2),0);
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($sheetData[$i]['G'])` and see what it contains that causes trouble.

Comment: @El_Vanja the value is string(1) "10", string(2) "20" how to convert it to numbers?

Comment: They should automatically be converted (that's what happens when you supply a valid numeric string). Might be some encoding that's messing this up, since it's reporting `string(1) "10"` (it should be `string(2)` since those are two characters). Add a cast to integer in the dump (`var_dump($sheetData[$i]['G'], (int) $sheetData[$i]['G'])`) and see if you get some values that don't match.